# Express middleware not catching errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

With using express and typescript I'm trying to create an middleware to catch errors like eq. Sentry, code is below:

```
 const catchError = (
  error: Error,
  req: Request,
  _res: Response,
  next: any
) => {
   console.log("ERROR: ", error);
   //some logic

  next(error);
}
```

index.ts

```
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit }));
  app.use(morgan("[:date[iso]] :method :url :status :response-time ms"));

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//controllers

app.use(catchError as express.ErrorRequestHandler)
```

why my middleware is working only when i put:

```
} catch (error) { 
   next(error);
}
```

in function where is an error and not working without it? This middleware should also catching errors and exceptions without using `next(error)`

thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you need to call method-override before the app uses the custom error handler.

Comment: @taipei can you show an example of what you think about?

Comment: Sure, I put it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a method override to use that custom error handler.

```js
const methodOverride = require('method-override')

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit }));
app.use(morgan("[:date[iso]] :method :url :status :response-time ms"));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Try to use this to override the custom error handler
app.use(methodOverride())

app.use(catchError as express.ErrorRequestHandler)
```

Reference:

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override